# Sitecore Lucene: content delivery server index not updating on publish

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I created a custom search page using the default `sitecore_web_index` and everything seemed to work until I migrated to my test environment that has separate content management and content delivery servers.  The index on the CD server is not getting updated on publish (the CM server does), if I rebuild the index from the control panel, I see updates.  So I believe the index and the search page are working correctly.

The index is using the `onPublishEndAsync` strategy. The Sitecore Search and Index Guide (http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_search_and_indexing_guide_sc70-usletter.pdf) section 4.4.2 states:

> This strategy does exactly what the name implies. During the initialization, it subscribes to the 
>   `OnPublishEnd` event and triggers an incremental index rebuild. With separate CM and CD servers, this 
>   event will be triggered via the `EventQueue` object, meaning that the `EventQueue` object needs to be 
>   enabled for this strategy to work in such environment.

My web.config has `<setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true"/>`

Also from the Search and Index Guide:

> **Processing**
>   The strategy will use the `EventQueue` object from the database it was initialized with:
>       `<param desc="database">web</param>`
>   This means that there are multiple criteria towards successful execution for this strategy:
>
> - This database must be specified in the `<databases />` section of the configuration file.
> - The `EnableEventQueues` setting must be set to true.
> - The `EventQueue` table within the preconfigured database should have entries dated later than 
>     index's last update timestamp.

I'm not sure of the `<param desc="database">web</param>` setting, because the publishing target (and database ID) for the CD server is `pub1`.  I tried changing `web` to `pub1`, but then neither servers' index was updated on a publish (so it's changed back to `web`).

The system was recently upgraded from Sitecore 6.5 to 7.2, so there are a couple indexes using `Sitecore.Search` API and these indexes are updated on publish.

Is the database param on the `EventQueue` wrong considering the multiple publishing targets?  Is there something else I'm missing, or perhaps a working example of a CM -> CD environment I could compare to?

TIA

EDIT:
If I wouldn't have had a co-worker sitting next to me both Friday and today who can confirm, I would think I'm going crazy.  But now, the CD server is getting updates to the index, but the CM server is not getting updates. What would make the CM server not get updates now?

Comment: Did you include ScalabilitySettings.config file inside your include folder on both CM and CD?

Comment: @AhmedOkour yes, ScalabilitySettings.config is included.

Comment: and what about SwitchMasterToWeb.config? is included in CD environment?

Comment: SwitchMasterToWeb.config was not being used, the CD server has a separately maintained web.config that has references to the master db removed.

Comment: in this case, you need to open a ticket for sitecore support

Comment: change your CrawlingLog to Debug and see if that highlights your problem http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-SearchLog-and-CrawlingLog.aspx

Comment: @ChristianHagelid changed to DEBUG, and saw this on the CM server  
`2728 20:56:55 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy triggered.
2728 20:56:55 DEBUG [Index=sitecore_web_index] Event Queue is empty. Incremental update returns`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into this same issue last night and have a more predictable resolution than creating a new IIS site:

**The resolve was to set a distinct InstanceName in ScalabilitySettings.config for each CD server, instead of relying on the auto-generated name.**

Setting this value *immediately* resolved the issue and restored the index update functionality upon Publish End Remote events.

**Note:** If you already *have* an InstanceName defined in your config, then you need to *change it* for this to work. I just increment the InstanceName with the date to force the change.

This is effectively fixing the same issue in the same way as the original poster did by changing to a new IIS site, as the OP's fix would have modified the auto-generated Instance Name based on the new IIS site name.

I believe the core problem with the OP (and also in my instance) is related to the EventQueue databases going out of sync with the CD instances and none of the servers being able to determine that an event has been generated / what content needs to update in the index. By changing the Instance Name (using either method) the servers appear to be new instances and start from scratch with their EventQueue tracking.

Every time I've seen issues like this in the past it's been related to major manipulations of Sitecore databases. Such as restorations, backup/restore to a new DB name, or rollbacks of databases due to deployment problems. I believe something in the above operations causes the EventQueues to get out of sync and the servers stop responding to the expected events.

Comment: This also worked immediately for us too. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I'm changing this solution to the accepted answer since it is more correct, and certainly more detailed. Thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone runs into this in the future, the solution that worked for me, was creating a new site in IIS manager.

I submitted a ticket to Sitecore support, but after a week of not getting a response, I attempted to recreate my dev environment on my test server.  I copied my local/dev files to the test CM server, created a new site and AppPool in IIS, pointed to the newly copied files, and updated the connectionstrings.config to point to the test environment database.  This worked (publishing updated the CM web index).

After trying to point the existing IIS site to my new files, and use the new AppPool, publishing from this site would not update the CM web index.

I then pointed my new site to the pre-existing files and pre-existing AppPool, and it still worked.  I disabled the pre-existing IIS site, edited the bindings on the new site to match the pre-existing one, and everything worked as it should.

I don't know what was "wrong" with the pre-existing site (I inherited the system, so I don't know how it was created), but comparing the bindings, basic settings, and advanced settings, they were a perfect match to the functional new IIS site.  I wish I had the real "cause" of the issue to share, but at least I found a solution that worked for me.

Thanks to all for the responses.

[EDIT] While this solution did work for me, please use Laver's answer as the correct solution for this issue.

Comment: This fix worked for me as well on Sitecore 7.2, although in my case we were using Solr and not Lucene.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it drove me nuts for a few months. I figured out that the answer lied in the rebuild strategy of the Lucene Index. The only way for Lucene to know to rebuild itself when the CM and CD are in separate instances of IIS, is for lucene to watch the EventQueue table and recognize that a change happened to an item that is either at the root, or child of the root that you specify in the crawler node. The strategy that you'll need to specify as the rebuild strategy to guarantee this behavior is below

```html
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
  <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />
</strategies>
```

If you use any other rebuild strategy with a remote instance of a content delivery server, the index will only be rebuilt in the CM instance's file system.

Comment: Straight to the point no fluff that's the way ahuh ahuh i like it!

Comment: Minor nit.  "contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild"

Answer (score 1):

@Laver's fix did work for us, but since our `InstanceName` is generated through our build process I did not want to have to change it. I did some more digging and found the root cause of the issue was data stored in the `core` database's `Properties` table.

You can see the full documentation in [this Sitecore Stack Exchange Q&A](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/lucene-indexes-not-updating-on-cd), but the solution is reproduced below.

> The solution requires an AppPool recycle to take effect:
>
> 1. Execute the following SQL statement against the `core` database
>
>    ```
>    DELETE FROM [Properties] WHERE [Key] LIKE '%_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP%'
>    ```
> 2. Recycle the CD's AppPool
>
> After this, you will want to rebuild the indexes on the CD so that
>   they pick up any changes that were missed while indexing was broken.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on the right track so far.  I believe what is tripping you up is the publishing target.  From what I understand you are using pub1 as your Content Delivery (CD) database.  It is a best practice to have a separate index defined for each database.  So you really should configure you CD server to be pointing to a sitecore_pub1_index and not the sitecore_web_index.

Your CM and CD servers should have your pub1 database configured.  An example of what that would look like would be something like this Sitecore include patch config.  It is a best practice t not edit the web.config directly if possible and use include config patches instead.  This example shows a patched config that would go in your \App_Config\Include directory:

```
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<databases>
  <database id="pub1" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <icon>Network/16x16/earth.png</icon>
    <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
    <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
      <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
        <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
        <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
          <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config"/>
          <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config"/>
        </prefetch>
      </dataProvider>
    </dataProviders>
    <proxiesEnabled>false</proxiesEnabled>
    <proxyDataProvider ref="proxyDataProviders/main" param1="$(id)"/>
    <archives hint="raw:AddArchive">
      <archive name="archive"/>
      <archive name="recyclebin"/>
    </archives>
    <cacheSizes hint="setting">
      <data>20MB</data>
      <items>10MB</items>
      <paths>500KB</paths>
      <itempaths>10MB</itempaths>
      <standardValues>500KB</standardValues>
    </cacheSizes>
  </database>
</databases>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You will then want to configure a pub1 search index on both your CM and CD servers.  Assuming you are using lucene that patch config would look like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="sitecore_pub1_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        </strategies>
        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>pub1</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
</contentSearch>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You now have a pub1 database and search index setup.  You should already have pub1 setup as a remote publishing target in Sitecore.  You also stated you have the EnableEventQueues setting configured to true on both CM and CD servers.

This is all you should need.  The onPublishEndAsync will keep an eye on the EventQueue table in your pub1 database.  When you publish to your pub1 publishing target you should see entries on your CD server's Sitecore log*.txt file with something similar to this:

```
ManagedPoolThread #7 23:21:00 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_pub1_index
ManagedPoolThread #7 23:21:00 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_pub1_index (units processed: )
```

Note: Units processed never seems to be accurately updated and is typically blank.  I assume this is a Sitecore bug but have never dug into enough to determine why it is not displaying in the logs correctly.  You can use Luke (again if you are using Lucene) to verify the index has updated as expected.

Comment: (Real question) why I would want pub1 on the CD server? The pub1 database on the CM server is the web database on the CD server.

Comment: @thadmiller you mention in your original question that "...because the publishing target (and database ID) for the CD server is pub1..." so I was just basing my answer on the information you provided.  If your CD servers are pointing to "web" the same applies, you want to make sure that you have indexes for your publishing targets (databases) and make sure that those index strategies are tied to the appropriate database.

Answer (score 0):

Check yours `publish:end:remote` event and see if there is any handler there. If so, try to remove all handlers to make sure they are not causing any error.

I had a similar issue when migrating from a Sitecore 6 to 7. The `EventArgs` for the remote publish in Sitecore 7 is different. The new type is `PublishEndRemoteEventArgs`.

Comment: The only handler in `publish:end:remote` is `Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer`. I tried removing that, which didn't fix the issue, and then my cache wasn't cleared on the CD server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution we did in our applicaiton, We have setup Web and Pub database and created addition publishingStrategy pointing it to the pub

```
<onPublishEndAsyncPub       type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy, 

Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">pub</param>
          <!-- whether full index rebuild should be triggered if the number of items in Event Queue exceeds 

Config.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold -->
          <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
        </onPublishEndAsyncPub>
```

in the index section set the newly created strategy to pub index

```
<index id="sitecore_pub_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="core">itembuckets</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsyncPub" />
          <!--<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />-->
            </strategies>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>pub</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Sitecore Scalability settings, please make sure this is correct.

The reason why the indexing is not being triggered on your CD servers is mainly due to your event queue. One quick check that you can perform is to see if there are events in the EventQueue table of the Core database which says that publishing has completed.

Also, check the **Sitecore.ContentSearch.config**, since when the publishing ends, it will trigger the rebuild index.

Thanks